# Why hide/show event is not working in safari

Tags: jquery, html

When the page loads I want all the dropdown option to hide. I tried this with CSS using `display: none`. I tried with jQuery. However none of these is working in Safari. The code works in Chrome but not in Safari.

I've tried:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".product_names option").hide();
  });
```

```js
jQuery("select").change(function() {
  $(".product_names option").hide();
});
```

```html
<select class="product_names">
  <option>Select option</option>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
  <option>Test4</option>
  <option>Test5</option>
</select>
```

and

```
jQuery(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    $('.product_names option').hide();
    });
```

```js
jQuery(document).on('change', 'select', function () {
    $('.product_names option').hide();
    });
```

```html
<select class="product_names">
  <option>Select option</option>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
  <option>Test4</option>
  <option>Test5</option>
</select>
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("select").change(function(){
           $("select option").hide();
      }); 
});
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("select").change(function(){
           $("select option").hide();
      }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="product_names">
  <option>Select option</option>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
  <option>Test3</option>
  <option>Test4</option>
  <option>Test5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] that replicates the problem.

Comment: `<option>` tags ignore almost all CSS in many browsers.

Comment: *"When the page loads, I want all the dropdown option to hide"* Your code is doing that when the user selects something from the select box, not when the page loads. (And *hiding* the options is...odd.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder  Yes, hiding all the option is odd...but i dont want to show up any of the select option but still i see all the option is showing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: Have you tried binding to window instead? `$(window).on('load', function(){ $("#product_names").children('option').hide();});`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that Safari ignores `display: none` on `option` elements.

Your best bet is probably to *disable* the options rather than hiding them:

```
$(".product_names").val("").find("option").prop("disabled", true);
```

If you *really* want them hidden, you'll need to remove them. You can always put them back if you want to later:

```
var options = $(".product_names").find("option").detach();
```

to add them back:

```
options.appendTo(".product_names");
```

Comment: Thanks, I like to detach the options but  I want to show the first option from the dropdown which says select option. Currently the detach() is hiding all the options from the dropdown

Comment: @PamuShinde - Just exclude the first one from the `find`, jQuery's [API](http://api.jquery.com/) is quite simple and well-documented. For instance, one way is `.find("option:not(:first)").`